# FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING como lo remplazo en este caso

Tags: php

lo que busco hacer es sanitizar esto y que solo quede el string, pero esto esta obsoleto y lo único que encuentro es `htmlspecialcharts` y no encuentro como usarlo en este caso o asi.

este es el codigo:

````
```$numero = '1HOLA';

$resultado = filter_var($numero, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

var_dump($resultado);```
````

es algo muy simple pero estoy aprendiendo y no entiendo ni encuentro como hacer que funcione

Comment: ¿Necesitas saber como utilizar `htmlspecialcharts` o una alternativa a `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` que haga lo mismo que `htmlspecialcharts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que requieres aquí no es una sanitización propiamente dicha, sino extraer los caracteres numéricos de una cadena.

Esto lo puedes hacer con [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php), por ejemplo:

```
$numero = '1HOLA';
$resultado= preg_replace('/[[:digit:]]/','', $numero);
var_dump($resultado);
```

**Salida:**

```
string(4) "HOLA"
```

`[[:digit:]]`, forma parte de lo que se conoce como [*Clases carácter*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) (*Character classes*), y en este caso extraerá todos los dígitos de la cadena. Ver varios ejemplos en [esta nota de contribución](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php#128198) en el Manual de PHP.

Cabe decir que `preg_replace()` te permite hacer reemplazos de varias cosas a la vez y resolver situaciones mucho más complejas que esta, mediante el uso de expresiones regulares (RegEX).

Comment: muchas gracias! me sirvió bastante para lo que buscaba hacer.